# How to create an object of string only on heap not in string pool?

Tags: java, string, heap-memory, string-pool

I want to create an object of string on the heap and I have to make sure that the object is not created on string pool.

Comment: Show your effort before you ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

Java by default doesn't put String objects into the string pool, instead, they give you the flexibility to explicitly store any arbitrary object in the string pool by calling `intern()`.

Use the `new` operator to force String class to create a new String object in heap space.

Also note, in Java 7 – the string pool was relocated to the main heap area from the permgen area of the heap.